# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int in - subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am working with an audio codec and trying to compress the audio file. For that, the Linux command is

```
opusenc --bitrate 16 input_file.wav output_file.opus
```

Now to run this command I am using subprocess, my code is

```
import subprocess
wav_file_path = '/home/mds-student/Documents/aDITYA/IEMOCAP/Ses01F_impro01.wav'
file_name = wav_file_path.split('.')[0]
file_name = os.path.basename(file_name)
bitrate = 16
cmd = ['opusenc', '--bitrate',bitrate ,wav_file_path, file_name, '.opus']
print(cmd)
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

This throws an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/9_opus_conversion_files.py", line 78, in <module>
    subprocess.call(cmd)
  File "/home/mds-student/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/home/mds-student/anaconda3/envs/venv/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1295, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the error message, and the first line (where the error 'started').  It is telling you an `int` is present where not expected.  Since you know `cmd` is a `list`, it is not the problem, then it is something within the list.  The only `int` in your list is `bitrate`, so a good idea is to convert it to one of those expected types.

Comment: @RufusVS Yes I converted bitrate into str, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the values in the `cmd` list should be converted to strings before passing it to `subprocess.call`.

`bitrate = 16` is an integer, that's why the error occurred.